# Identify labels which are not displayed in a dense area to later ensure display of all lables

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am creating a map with many labels in a dense area in QGIS.

Already I am able to manually position the labels to show more information.

Is there a way to identify / highlight those features which are currently not displayed so that I can ensure by manually moving that all features are visible in the final map?

[image: This is what I currently have]

(Map data copyright OdBL OpenStreetMap Contributors)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I found the feature a minute later by accidentally clicking on the toolbar:

[image: Button: display non-placed lables]

Comment: Wow! I found QGIS documentation about label toolbar https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-label-toolbar